# Include static lib in dynamic lib

Tags: object, g++, shared-libraries, archive

I have the following problem :

- several object files a1.o, a2.o, a3.o, ...
- an archive libxxxx.a.
  The archive libxxxx.a only contains object files : b1.o, b2.o etc...

I would like to create a shared library (.so) from all the object files.

Problem : If I use :

```
g++ -shared libxxxx.a a1.o a2.o ... -o libnew.so
```

g++ does understand that I want to link with the static library libxxxx.a and does not include all the symbols of the archive.

A simple workaround is to first expand the archive using `ar -x` and then create the lib but it's not really "elegant".

There must be a simple command to force g++ to include the whole archive in the .so but I can't find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man ld`:

> **--whole-archive**
>              For each archive mentioned on the command line after the --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in the
>              link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>              library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>
> Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.
>              Second, don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your
>              link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.

Example:

```
g++ -shared -o yourlib a.o. b.o. c.o -Wl,-whole-archive libstatic.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

Note also that in your example you first put static library, then the object files - in this case the symbols used in the object files and defined in static library will not be found unless you use `--whole-archive` linker option. If you want to include just the needed symbols from the static library, you need to put it `after` the object files.

```
g++ -o your_app a.o b.o c.o -lyour_static_lib
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was exactly what I was looking for. I had missed this flag during my searchs !