# Linking error with cmake

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, static-libraries

I'm trying to understand why I get a linking error while compiling a project generated with CMake.

The CMakeFiles.txt builds a static library for each folder of the project and then link all of them together in the following way:

```
# root CMakeLists.txt

add_subdirectory(subfolder1)
add_subdirectory(subfolder2)
add_subdirectory(...)

add_executable(target ${SOURCES})

set(LIBRARIES
  LIB_FOO
  LIB_BAR
  ...
)

target_link_libraries(target
  ${LIBRARIES}
)
```

then in each subfolder I have a simple CMakeLists.txt like

```
file(GLOB FOO_SOURCE *.cpp)
add_library(LIB_FOO ${FOO_SOURCE})
```

Now this works and compiles everything fine but I get an undefined reference while linking, so I tried to investigate if everything was available at the end and it looks like so. The actual error is the following:

```
libLIB_WORLD.a(World.cpp.o): In function `World::generate(WorldGenOptions)':
World.cpp:(.text+0x803): undefined reference to `MapGenerator::MapGenerator(BlockMap*)'
World.cpp:(.text+0x837): undefined reference to `MapGenerator::generate(bool, WorldGenOptions)'
```

Now, MapGenerator.cpp is part of `LIB_MAP`, so I checked if the file exists and contains the symbols:

```
:~$ nm libLIB_MAP.a | grep generate
....
00000000000044dc T _ZN12MapGenerator8generateEb15WorldGenOptions

:~$ nm CMakeFiles/LIB_MAP.dir/MapGenerator.cpp.o | grep generate
....
00000000000044dc T _ZN12MapGenerator8generateEb15WorldGenOptions
```

So the symbol is present, at this point I checked if it was correctly linked by ld:

```
:~$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/g++  ... libLIB_MAP.a libLIB_WORLD.a ...
```

So it is actually present in linking phase together with the other library that is not able to find the symbol.

Is there something trivial I'm missing? I'm quite new to CMake so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You may need to check the order of libs provided for linker

Comment: @Steephen: the order is the one written by `VERBOSE=1` at the end of the question, `LIB_MAP` is linked before `LIB_WORLD`

Comment: @Steephen: swapping the order of LIB_MAP and LIB_WORLD seems to have fixed the problem. So WORLD (which requires MAP) is linked before the other.

Comment: @Steephen I just trimmed down the invocation because it links against 40-50 libraries + 15 shared ones, I wanted to concentrate on the issue.

Comment: CMake would normally [take care of the correct order of libraries passed to the linker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204820/cmake-and-order-dependent-linking-of-shared-libraries), but I nonetheless recommend using `--start-group` `--end-group` [linker options for the GNU toolchain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141383/linking-a-shared-library-with-statics-using-cmake). It increases link time, but with so many libraries somewhere might even be a cyclic dependency.

Comment: @Florian Introducing toolchain-specific flags like this sort of undermines the purpose of CMake as a portable build tool. CMake is quite capable of handling these problems on its own when used correctly. Unfortunately, it is sometimes not obvious what correct usage of CMake looks like ;)

Comment: @ComicSansMS You are right. Let's just say it was the last resort I used when I introduced CMake to an existing project of a similar size. I was going through the library dependencies for months and still ended up with some 3rd party libraries that needed the grouping. And I didn't put it into the `CMakeLists.txt` files itself (like in the post I linked), but put it only - where it was needed - in my GNU ARM cross-compiling toolchain with `SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> -o <TARGET> --start-group <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> --end-group")`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a problem of a library dependency that was not modeled correctly in CMake.

Your `LIB_WORLD` references methods from `LIB_MAP`. This dependency is not modeled in your CMake scripts. As both of those are static libraries, they will still build fine on their own. (Remember that static libraries are essentially a bunch of object files packed together, but they never pass through the linker.)

However, as soon as you link them to an executable or a shared library, you will get the problem. Even though your executable links against both `LIB_WORLD` and `LIB_MAP`, it does so *in the wrong order*. So when the linker is trying to resolve the missing symbols for `LIB_WORLD`, it does not know yet about the symbols exported by `LIB_MAP`, hence the error message you experienced.

The proper fix is to introduce the dependency on `LIB_WORLD`:

```
add_library(LIB_WORLD [...])
target_link_libraries(LIB_WORLD LIB_MAP)
```

Now whenever you link something against `LIB_WORLD` you will always also link against `LIB_MAP` and *CMake will take care that the order is right*. (In particular, if your executable does not make direct use of methods from `LIB_MAP` you might want to remove it from its `target_link_libraries` altogether.)

As an additional benefit, it now allows you to build `LIB_WORLD` as a shared library, which would have failed with a linker error before.

Comment: You just saved me so much time. THANK YOU! This needs to be accepted as correct answer. Although this is totally counter intuitive to me. I would have thought you wanted to link to the LIB_MAP first, because those symbols need to be linked against on the subsequent LIB_WORLD linkage.... My brain still doesn't quite want to understand this, but it's early, maybe more coffee..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spend a few hours trying to figure it out by myself.